# Is there any query in Android Room for advance searching?

Tags: search, android-room, dao

at first apologize for poor English.

i have a `EditText` and i wanna implement advance search scenario where have a `String` that has  3 or more words in `EditText` and when i know two words of string show me the row.
for example i have a `String` like "*Touch Screen Assembly*".i know "*Touch*" and "*Assembly*" and i write *Touch Assembly* in `EditText`.but Room can't show me any row.

[when i write touch word show me row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWWkA.jpg)

[but when i write first word and third any row show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHBI0.jpg)

and my Room Query is `@Query("SELECT * FROM tbl_dataItem WHERE productName LIKE  '%'||:keyword||'%' ")
    Single<List<DataItem>> search(String keyword);`

[this is `EditText` code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4yIN.jpg)